# Displaying Salesforce dashboard on home page using visual force page in Homepage component

Tags: dashboard, home-page-component

I am trying to put 15 dashboards on home page using Home page component and visualforce page.

I am successfully able to display dashboard on home page. But on right click "Open in new tab" or "open in new window" option is disabled.

i used Location.href =" " to reference dashboard page in VF.

Comment: browsers generally show those options on links. the dashboards rendered on the home page are not links, so you might not get those options when you right click on the dashboards.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this functionality.  Please suggest.